# transferring node app to server

Tags: javascript, node.js, nginx

I have a node server file, `app.js` which uses `express`.

The file looks like this

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express();
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'))

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello World!')
})

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!')
});
```

If I run `$ node app.js` from my terminal it launches and if I navigate to `localhost:3000` on my machine I see `Hello World!`.

I have uploaded the file to a server and try and navigate to the `index.html`  file , which is in the `public` folder, however it doesn't work.

Maybe I am missing many steps, but can anyone advise how I can launch the `node` app on my server?

Comment: Do you have access to a terminal/console on your server?

Comment: @DevDig i do have access to console on the server

Answer (score 1):

Your server doesn't send index.html anywhere. It only serves "/" path by sending text "Hello World!".

With Node.js, you have to tell which content you want to send for each route.

You can simply send the specific file : (sure, but dirty)

```
app.get('/index.html', function (req, res) {
  res.send(PATH_TO_FILE/index.html);
});
```

Or specify which path to use to serve files by default :

`app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));`

And you put all your public files to serve automatically in the public folder :

```
YOUR_PROJECT/public/AUTOMATICALLY_SERVED_FILES
```

Where `AUTOMATICALLY_SERVED_FILES` can be `index.html` or `css/style.css` for exemple.

NB : NGINX is not useful at this point.

Comment: I actually have set up the dirname etc. i have updated the question. it still doesn't serve the files. Thanks for your response. i think i need to follow the guidelines set out by  federico lucca

Answer (score 0):

On the server, nodejs is configured right?

I use [forever](https://github.com/foreverjs/forever) with nodejs, it is useful if you would like to use nodejs like a service on linux base system.

Comment: when you say "configured", what exactly needs to be done? just install node on the server?

Comment: if you use nginx you must create a proxy to port 3000,if you use nodejs standalone check if the firewall rules were right

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-node-js-application-for-production-on-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: i do have access to the console on my server. Does that make it easier?

Comment: yes,follow the tutorial and check nginx configuration.

Comment: finaly i just decide to use nodejs standalone,i have some issue with the ram

Comment: I guess what federico said sums it up completely. using nginx and node together means you need to create and setup nginx as a reverse proxy so that it can reach the upstream properly. And also, if you are not doing that and want to use direct node (at port 3000 in your case) then please check that port 3000 is open to accept, otherwise you need to use iptables to open the port.